# Is it possible to decrypt a substring of a ciphertext?

Tags: security, encryption, aes

Given some ciphertext for a plaintext message encrypted using e.g. AES256, is it possible to take an arbitrary substring of the ciphertext and decrypt it to reveal part of the original plaintext? I tried it with aespipe and it didn't seem to work. Are there any tricks that can be played to support this? What if instead of an arbitrary substring, I wanted to decrypt only certain specific substrings (e.g. if the ciphertext is divided into blocks according to some predefined block size and we only want to decrypt whole blocks)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CTR mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29) can decrypt subsets of encrypted data.

[XTS mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption_theory#XEX-based_tweaked-codebook_mode_with_ciphertext_stealing_.28XTS.29) is used for disk encryption where disk-sized blocks can be individually decrypted.

[ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29) can be used but it too is insecure, see ECB mode and scroll down to the Penguin.

[CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29) can **not** be used nor other chaining modes.

Comment: Thanks, that's roughly what I was looking for. I upvoted both you and Daniel but I'll give you the correct answer as you've given more detail.

Comment: You actually up-voted two Daniel's, "zaph" is not my real, who knew ;-)

Comment: Haha, even more bizarrely my name is Daniel too!

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the mode of operation. In ECB, for example, each block is encrypted separately so you can select a single block and decypt it.

Comment: Do not use ECB mode, it too is insecure.